# Java takes long to convert a 5 letter word to numbers

Tags: java

Before I start I would like to inform you that I am a total beginner to Java so excuse my uneducated mistakes. I have been trying to program an application to encrypt a message. During this process, the input gets converted to a number to allow mathematical expressions. The problem is when trying to convert. The actual code does work, but takes a rather long time to convert a 5 letter word, which is the word "Hello"( it takes around 10 seconds or so). Below is the method where the input gets converted.  `

```
public static  void encrypt(String plainText) {

    Random random = new Random();

    plainText =plainText.toUpperCase();
    char[] storedInput = plainText.toCharArray();
    int[] convertedInput = new int[plainText.length()];


    for (int indexSelector = 0, comparisonNumber = 1; indexSelector < plainText.length();  comparisonNumber++) {
        if( storedInput[indexSelector] == ' ') {
            System.out.print(" <SPACE> ");
        }
        else {
            if( ((int) storedInput[indexSelector]-64) == comparisonNumber) {
                int converter = storedInput[indexSelector] - 64;
                convertedInput[indexSelector] = converter;
                System.out.print(convertedInput[indexSelector]);

            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code takes an input (hello), turns all letters to upper case, and then when I get the integer I subtract 64 because it returns the ASCII integer. After this A becomes 1, B becomes 2, C becomes 3 and so on.... 
When I try to convert hello (or any other words) it takes at least 8 seconds. Any suggestions on why?

Comment: What are you trying to do with comaprisonNumber? You are looping through all 4 billion possible integers every letter since you aren't using it but requiring it be equal to your letter first.

Comment: try converting a string that starts with a space and see how long that takes.

Comment: Does it run quickly with input "HELLO"? I think that it is taking a long time because you're not handling lower case correctly. Note that `plainText.toUpperCase()` doesn't change `plainText`.

Comment: If you're simply trying to substitute A to 1, B to 2 etc, why isn't you for loop just invoking `convertedValue[i] = storedInput[i] - 'A' + 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simplify your program. `comparisonNumber` is causing you significant problems, and you generally should avoid multiple variables in your `for` loop unless you really know what you are doing. Even in professional settings I would consider a `,` in a `for` loop a problem that needs to be justified.

In your case you are looping on `comparisonNumber` but never using it for anything but verifying you hit the right number, where you then ignore the value and do operations that are independent of it. Since you don't reset the value, it loops through all the possible values before continuing to process the next letter.

Here is a version that might be closer to what you are looking for, I just removed that variable and left everything else as is.

```
public static  void encrypt(String plainText) {

    Random random = new Random();

    plainText.toUpperCase();
    char[] storedInput = plainText.toCharArray();
    int[] convertedInput = new int[plainText.length()];


    for (int indexSelector = 0; indexSelector < plainText.length();  indexSelector++) {
    if( storedInput[indexSelector] == ' ') {
        System.out.print(" <SPACE> ");
    } else {
        int converter = storedInput[indexSelector] - 64;
        convertedInput[indexSelector] = converter;
        System.out.print(convertedInput[indexSelector]);
        indexSelector++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha sorry for that, and thank you! I am very new to this and my mistakes are quite embarrassing. Thank you again! :)